# Como criar uma lista personalizada usando dados de quatro tabelas?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
Nota
{
    int id;
    int idFornecedor;
    int idProduto;
    int idClasse;
}
```

e tenho as respectivas classes referentes aos ids da classe anterior:

```
Fornecedor
{
    int id;
    string descricao;
}

Produto
{
    int id;
    string descricao;
}

Classe
{
    int id;
    string descricao;
}
```

Como faço pra criar uma lista usando Lambda ou LINQ que me retorne o seguinte resultado:

```
NotaCompleta
{
    int id;
    int idFornecedor;
    int idProduto;
    int idClasse;
    string fornecedorDescricao;
    string produtoDescricao;
    string classeDescricao;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segue uma consulta [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) e outra [lambda](/questions/tagged/lambda).
*Esta é apenas outra forma de resolver.*

**Variáveis para usar no LINQ**

```
var notas = new List<Nota>();
var fornecedores = new List<Fornecedor>();
var produtos = new List<Produto>();
var classes = new List<Classe>();
```

**Populacionando para exemplo**

```
var nota1 = new Nota { id = 1, idFornecedor = 1, idProduto = 1, idClasse = 1 };
var nota2 = new Nota { id = 1, idFornecedor = 1, idProduto = 2, idClasse = 2 };
var fornecedor1 = new Fornecedor { id = 1, descricao = "Fornecedor1" };
var produto1 = new Produto { id = 1, descricao = "Produto1" };
var produto2 = new Produto { id = 2, descricao = "Produto2" };
var classe1 = new Classe { id = 1, descricao = "Classe1" };
var classe2 = new Classe { id = 2, descricao = "Classe2" };

notas.Add(nota1);
notas.Add(nota2);
fornecedores.Add(fornecedor1);
produtos.Add(produto1);
produtos.Add(produto2);
classes.Add(classe1);
classes.Add(classe2);
```

**Para utilizar no LAMBDA**

```
var notasQ = new EnumerableQuery<Nota>(notas);
var fornecedoresQ = new EnumerableQuery<Fornecedor>(fornecedores);
var produtosQ = new EnumerableQuery<Produto>(produtos);
var classesQ = new EnumerableQuery<Classe>(classes);
```

**Consulta LINQ**

```
var NotaCompletaLINQ = from no in notas
                       join fo in fornecedores on no.idFornecedor equals fo.id
                       join pr in produtos on no.idProduto equals pr.id
                       join cl in classes on no.idClasse equals cl.id
                       select new {
                           no.id,
                           no.idFornecedor,
                           no.idProduto,
                           no.idClasse,
                           fornecedorDescricao = pr.descricao,
                           produtoDescricao = pr.descricao,
                           classeDescricao = cl.descricao
                       };
```

**Consulta LAMBDA**

```
var NotaCompletaLAMBDA = notasQ
    .Join(fornecedoresQ, nota => nota.idFornecedor, forn => forn.id, (nota, forn) => new { nota, forn })
    .Join(produtosQ, nota => nota.nota.idProduto, prod => prod.id, (nota, prod) => new { nota.nota, nota.forn, prod })
    .Join(classesQ, nota => nota.nota.idClasse, clas => clas.id, (nota, clas) => new { nota.nota, nota.forn, nota.prod, clas })
    .Select(x => new {
        x.nota.id,
        x.nota.idFornecedor,
        x.nota.idProduto,
        x.nota.idClasse,
        fornecedorDescricao = x.forn.descricao,
        produtoDescricao = x.prod.descricao,
        classeDescricao = x.clas.descricao
    });
```

**Obs**
Foi necessário transformar seus campos em propriedades (simplificada).

```
public class Nota {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idFornecedor { get; set; }
    public int idProduto { get; set; }
    public int idClasse { get; set; }
}

public class Fornecedor {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Produto {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Classe {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar Join com expresões Lambda:

```
    List<Fornecedor> forecedores = new List<Fornecedor>() 
    {
        new Fornecedor() { id=1, descricao="forn1" },
        new Fornecedor() { id=2, descricao="forn2" },
        new Fornecedor() { id=3, descricao="forn3" },
        new Fornecedor() { id=4, descricao="forn4" }
    };

    List<Produto> produtos = new List<Produto>() 
    {
        new Produto() { id=1, descricao="prod1" },
        new Produto() { id=2, descricao="prod2" },
        new Produto() { id=3, descricao="prod3" },
        new Produto() { id=4, descricao="prod4" }
    };

    List<Classe> classes = new List<Classe>() 
    {
        new Classe() { id=1, descricao="clas1" },
        new Classe() { id=2, descricao="clas2" },
        new Classe() { id=3, descricao="clas3" },
        new Classe() { id=4, descricao="clas4" }
    };

    List<Nota> notas = new List<Nota>() 
    {
        new Nota() { id=1, idFornecedor=1, idProduto=2,idClasse=2},
        new Nota() { id=2, idFornecedor=2, idProduto=3,idClasse=3},
        new Nota() { id=3, idFornecedor=4, idProduto=1,idClasse=1}
    };

    int idNotaCompleta = 1;

    var notasCompletas = 
        from nota in notas
            join produto in produtos on nota.idProduto equals produto.id
            join fornecedor in forecedores on nota.idFornecedor equals fornecedor.id
            join classe in classes on nota.idClasse equals classe.id
            select new NotaCompleta() 
            {
                id = idNotaCompleta++,
                idFornecedor = fornecedor.id,
                idProduto = produto.id,
                idClasse = classe.id,
                fornecedorDescricao = fornecedor.descricao,
                produtoDescricao = produto.descricao,
                classeDescricao = classe.descricao
            };
```

Exemplo funcionando no .Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2uooAR

Answer (score 2):

Mais simples atualizar sua `Nota`

```
class Nota
{
    int id;
    Fornecedor Fornecedor;
    Produto Produto;
    Classe Classe;
}
```

Assim basta usar:

```
var nota = GetNotaPorId(idNota);
var fornecedor = nota.Fornecedor.Descricao;
```

Esse seria o mais simples, já que dentro de `Fornecedor`, `Produto` e `Classe` já possuem `id`, nao haveria motivo para duplicar essas propriedades em `Nota`.

Apenas usando seu cenário - mas eu totalmente não recomendo:

```
var notaCompleta = db.notas.Select(nota => new 
{
    nota.Id,
    nota.IdFornecedor,
    nota.IdProduto,
    nota.Classe,
    FornecedorDescricao = db.Fornecedores.Single(f => f.Id == nota.IdFornecedor).Descricao,
    ProdutoDescricao = db.Produtos.Single(p => p.Id == nota.IdProduto).Descricao,
    ClasseDescricao = db.Classes.Single(c => c.Id == nota.IdClasse).Descricao
}
```

Comment: me diz uma coisa, essas classes são criadas automaticamente via Entity Framework. Como eu posso fazer o exemplo que você citou acima?

Comment: Vc fez engenharia reversa então para criar a classe, certo? O que quer dizer que vc fez **Database First** No sentido contrario, vc fazer **Code First**.  De uma olhada nesse meu repositório do GitHub sobre [como começar com CodeFirst](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD). Pode ajudar.